# DOT.files in javascript? What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, file, filelist

I'm currently working off a sample code found online of a file reader which I need some assistance deciphering.

```
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
        alert('Please select a file!');
        return;
    }
    //var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(files[0], "UTF-8");
```

In this part of the code, I want to know how javascript interprets the .files in document.getElementById('files').files or what the variable files is stored as.

I printed out files right after I set it to see what it prints in the console and I still don't understand what it means.
[image]

What I'm trying to do is change files so it loops through an array to get every specific value instead of just one.

Comment: It says it right there, `... .files` returns a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

Comment: `files` is a FileList which is an arraylike object (has a length and 0,1,2... keys)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: And try not to learn from w3schools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at a console log of an object if it is an instance object (ie made from a constructor function) it will have a name preceding it's details. In this case that name is `FileList`. You can use that name in a search query to look up information about it's structure and other details.

For instance searching "javascript FileList" one of the top results will be [MDN's documentation about that structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).

Simply it is just an array-like object. Meaning it has numeric property keys that hold it's items (files), and a `length` property telling the number of items it holds.

With this you should realize you can use a regular for loop to iterate over its contents

```
for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
  let file=files[i];
  console.log(file.name);
}
```

Note FileList also has a [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) meaning it can create its own iterator. So this means you can also use a `for ... of` loop with the structure

```
for(let file of files){
  console.log(file.name);
}
```

If you are wanting to read in each file with FileReader you will need to call the code you were using inside a loop

```
for(let file of files){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(){
       //store data somewhere
    }
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object that lives in `.files` is a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). It works basically like an array; it has a `.length`, and you can access items with `[]`. But the people who wrote the standard decided to make it its own special type of object, instead of a normal array. Presumably this is to prevent you from doing silly things like replacing some of its entries with other objects.

To loop over it you can do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var oneFile = files[i];
    // Do something with oneFile here
}
```

Each of the files in there is a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), which has some properties that you can see in the screenshot you posted (`name`, `lastModified`, `lastModifiedDate`, etc.). To get the data out of each of them, you can use a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) as you demonstrate in your question, but doing it inside the loop on `oneFile` rather than at the end on `files[0]`.